# Load same class by name from different JAR dependencies in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, classloader

Our Grails app talks to a proprietary JDBC database; we have concurrent versions of this database in production (v4 and v5), and unfortunately the JDBC driver for v4 does not work with v5. The driver class name is identical between the libraries, and that's the problem; we can't differentiate them at runtime when loading both libraries.

I know this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2418977/791406) for Java, the recommended solution being custom class loaders, but I want to avoid that if possible.

I was hoping Grails offered an easy solution using `BuildConfig.groovy`, but could not find anything on the topic.

Comment: Just wondering - v5 driver does not work with v4 database? It's not backwards compatible?

Comment: Sure you can implement a custom class loader with an instance of [GrailsClassLoader](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsClassLoader.html). With MOP, you can  use the loadClass() method at runtime

Comment: You could try using a tool like [JarJar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to re-package one of the versions into a different package name.

Comment: @lukelazarovic it's not, that's the issue ;-)